# drop down animation for a custom Popup

Tags: android, popup, spinner, dropdown, slide

I want to make a layout appear as a popup with a spinner like dropdown animation , dropping down from the Button that was clicked

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parentRecyclerView.context)
                    val priceSlide = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_popup, parentRecyclerView, false)
                    val slideUp: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parentRecyclerView.context, R.anim.slide_up)
                    priceSlide.startAnimation(slideUp)
```

the slide_up.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

this doesnt do anything. What's missing?

the layout in question is a constraintLayout 100dpx200dp with a couple of views inside